# CSS weirdness in firefox - float left not floating left, unless large width is used

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome

I have a problem

```
 #column-left {
     float: left;
     width: 350px;
 }
```

will float left, but when I make the width smaller

with this:
         `#column-left {
                   float: left;
               width: 250px;
     }`

it doesn't work. Both forms work in chrome, but not in firefox. Any ideas?

Here are some images to illustrate: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDIs3.jpg

Comment: Can you give the website link or create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: http://bit-metals.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=66


Currently it's at the functioning width

Comment: Show enough code to reproduce the problem rather than a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your CSS code as below.

Remove `float: left;` and `width: 350px;` from `#column-left`.

Add `position: absolute;` to `#column-left`

Change `margin-left: 220px;` on `#content`

This will do the magic. Tested on Firefox and Google Chrome.

Comment: works a dream. Cheers! Can you tell my why my original css didn't work?

Comment: Your website width is not fixed. You set it as `auto`. So the elements will flow on screen. ie, different screen resolution brings you different layout. That may be your problem. not sure. :)