# Float left not working in browser

Tags: html, css

the code on the link below, works fine on jsfiddle, but unfortunately float: lefft is not working on chrome/firefox. Any pointers in this direction will be helpful.

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/YMsR4/5/)

```
<div class='list' id='list1' style='padding: 1px; border : 5px groove; min-width: 3px; width: auto; min-height: 3px; height: auto; ' >
    <div class='tuple tuple1' id='tuple1_1' style='padding: 2px; border : 1px solid; min-width: 3px; width: auto; min-height: 3px; height: auto;' >
        <div class='elmnt elmnt1 elmnt1_1' id='elmnt1_1' style='padding: 2px; border : 1px dotted; position: relative; left: 6px;  min-width: 3px; width: 100; min-height: 3px; height: auto;' >
            <div class='list' id='list2' style='padding: 1px; border : 5px groove; min-width: 3px; width: auto; min-height: 3px; height: auto; ' >
                <div class='tuple tuple2' id='tuple2_1' style='padding: 2px; border : 1px solid; min-width: 3px; width: auto; min-height: 3px; height: auto; overflow: hidden;' >
                    <div class='elmnt elmnt2 elmnt2_1' id='elmnt2_1' style='padding: 2px; border : 1px dotted; min-width: 3px; width: auto; min-height: 3px; height: auto; float : left;' >jdk-7u11-linux-i586.rpm</div>
                    <div class='elmnt elmnt2 elmnt2_2' id='elmnt2_2' style='padding: 2px; border : 1px dotted; min-width: 3px; width: auto; min-height: 3px; height: auto; float : left;' >107M </div>                  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If it works fine in the fiddle, what's the point of posting it? Post one that shows your issue.

Comment: copy and paste the code as an html file, run it and you will find that the divs do not float left, that the issue @j08691

Comment: perhaps these would help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572340/css-weirdness-in-firefox-float-left-not-floating-left-unless-large-width-is-u

http://www.hotscripts.com/forums/css/35950-float-left-working-everywhere-but-firefox.html

Comment: Why would pasting it in a file to run locally make any difference from the fiddle?

Comment: that is exactly my question! @j08691

Comment: What is going wrong? Can we see an example of it breaking? Screen-shot?

Comment: I think it is very likely that if you actually ran the file off a server and gave people the link instead of asking people to save and run it locally, you'd get the answer much quicker. I'm pretty sure James caught it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in behaviour is due to whether you have a DOCTYPE or not. If you create a full html file with a DOCTYPE at the top, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

then it should work as expected.

Quoting from the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-doctype):

> DOCTYPEs are required for legacy reasons. When omitted, browsers tend to use a different rendering mode that is incompatible with some specifications. Including the DOCTYPE in a document ensures that the browser makes a best-effort attempt at following the relevant specifications.